# CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap horizontal form with nested inline form

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.3

I am using the [TwitterBootstrap Plugin](https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap) for CakePHP2.x. And I can't get the combination of a horizontal form with a nested inline form to work.

part of my code:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Event', array('class' => 'form-horizontal'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Event.short_name',array(
        'label' => 'Short name', 
        'type' => 'text', 
        'class' => 'span5'
    ));
?>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">Date & Time</div>
    <div class="controls form-inline">
        <div class=" input-append">
            <?php 
                echo $this->Form->input('Event.start_date', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'type' => 'text', 
                    'class' => 'span2 start_date', 
                    'after' => '<span class="add-on datetime"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>'
                ));

                echo $this->Form->input('Event.end_date', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'type' => 'text', 
                    'class' => 'span2 end_date', 
                    'after' => '<span class="add-on"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>'
                ));
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example this happens:
[image: capture]

and the generated html

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">Date & Time</div>
    <div class="controls form-inline">
        <div class=" input-append">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="data[Event][start_date]" class="span2 start_date" type="text" value="2013-06-15" id="EventStartDate" required="required"><span class="add-on"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="data[Event][end_date]" class="span2 end_date" type="text" value="2013-06-22" id="EventEndDate" required="required"><span class="add-on"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add 'div' -> false to the two date form field they move inline but the padding etc is gone.
[image: capture]

and the generated html

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">Date & Time</div>
    <div class="controls form-inline">
        <div class=" input-append">
            <input name="data[Event][start_date]" class="span2 start_date" type="text" value="2013-06-15" id="EventStartDate" required="required"><span class="add-on"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>
            <input name="data[Event][end_date]" class="span2 end_date" type="text" value="2013-06-22" id="EventEndDate" required="required"><span class="add-on"><span class="icon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this is due to the fact that all form fields are placed in controls divs... Does anyone know how to solve this?

I also posted this as an issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap/issues/68), since I think it has to do with the plugin, but I hope someone knows a temp workarround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work. I used it before and it looks like this:

[image]

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event', array(
'class' => 'form-horizontal',
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
    'div' => array('class' => 'control-group'),
    'label' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
    'between' => '<div class="controls">',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'error' => array('attributes' => array(
            'wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline'
    )),
)));?>
<fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('Event.start_date', array(
        'label' => array('class' => 'control-label',
            'text' => 'start date'),
    ));?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is with a part of the form inline. The horizontal form works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be conflict between TB and Cake about float and clear, because cake.generic.css sets for form div clear:both which moves elements below instead of next to.

Try this:

```
div.form-inline div{
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: I moved away from Cake because of the way they dealth with forms. Currently I'm exploring Laravel. Thanks for the help.